# who gets bitcoin transaction fees and how much are they worth, in general?

Tags: transaction-fees

Antpool says it keeps transaction fees to give to their engineers.

How much does amount to, in general?  Is it the 50 bitcoins or whatever it is?  Or is it a different amount?

Comment: To answer the second half of your question, it's usually pretty small relative to the block subsidy.

Comment: You can go to http://blockr.io/ and look at the "block fee" column to see how much in fees was collected with recent blocks.  It seems to be averaging around 1-2 BTC per block.